# opencv feature detection access violation

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, feature-detection, surf

i have a task to implement a image align code with opencv in QT. So i tried to do it with the SURF Feature Detector. 
The interesting code is the following:

**my QT .pro file**

```
INCLUDEPATH += E:\Programme\opencv\build\include\opencv2
LIBS += -LE:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_calib3d2413d.lib \
    E:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_nonfree2413d.lib \
    E:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_highgui2413d.lib \
    E:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_features2d2413d.lib \
    E:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_core2413d.lib \
    E:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_flann2413d.lib \
    E:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\opencv_imgproc2413d.lib \
```

Yes, i tried to link them relative and do it with one long path and then only the file names, but that didn't run. But i think thats not so important...

**my includes**

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "cvmatandqimage.h"  
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

cvmatandqimage.h comes from this project: [QImage to OpenCV matrix](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtOpenCV)

**the main file**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    using namespace cv;

    initModule_nonfree();

    SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

    QImageReader reader(inputFiles.at(0));
    QImage image1 = reader.read();
    reader.setFileName(inputFiles.at(1));
    QImage image2 = reader.read();

    Mat cvColorImage1 = QtOcv::image2Mat(image1, CV_8UC3, QtOcv::MCO_RGB);
    Mat cvColorImage2 = QtOcv::image2Mat(image2, CV_8UC3, QtOcv::MCO_RGB);
    Mat cvGrayscaleImage1;
    Mat cvGrayscaleImage2;
    cvtColor(cvColorImage1,cvGrayscaleImage1,CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvtColor(cvColorImage2,cvGrayscaleImage2,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    std::vector<KeyPoint> current_keypoints1, current_keypoints2;
    Mat current_descriptors1, current_descriptors2;

    detector.detect( cvGrayscaleImage1, current_keypoints1);
    detector.detect( cvGrayscaleImage2, current_keypoints2);


...
}
```

Ok. Now to **my Problem**:
On debugging it crashes at `detector.detect( cvGrayscaleImage1, current_keypoints1);`

The error is most times `Exception at 0x..., code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0`

Sometimes it only says `error detected: execution can not be coninued`
And some other times it gets in to the next line and crashes there.

The opencv grayscale images look ok on debugging. So i think the detector is false. But i mostly have the same code like in the opencv documentation.
I included the nonfree library, linked it and initialized it.
I have no idea what i'm making wrong.

Hope you can give me some hints.

**EDIT:**

Ok i figured it out.
It was the wrong linking.
This works for Debug-mode:

```
LIBS += -LE:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\
        -lopencv_calib3d2413d \
        -lopencv_nonfree2413d \
        -lopencv_highgui2413d \
        -lopencv_features2d2413d \
        -lopencv_core2413d \
        -lopencv_flann2413d \
        -lopencv_imgproc2413d \
```

But why is this working only for debug too?

```
CONFIG(debug) {
   LIBS += -LE:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\
        -lopencv_calib3d2413d \
        -lopencv_nonfree2413d \
        -lopencv_highgui2413d \
        -lopencv_features2d2413d \
        -lopencv_core2413d \
        -lopencv_flann2413d \
        -lopencv_imgproc2413d \
} else {
    LIBS += -LE:\Programme\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib\
        -lopencv_calib3d2413 \
        -lopencv_nonfree2413 \
        -lopencv_highgui2413 \
        -lopencv_features2d2413 \
        -lopencv_core2413 \
        -lopencv_flann2413 \
        -lopencv_imgproc2413 \
}
```

Comment: You need to link to only debug libraries when in debug, or only release libraries when in release.

Comment: Ok i deleted the release lines, but the error is the same...